# Http Serving with node.js over the web

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

This is a very basic question.  But I have looked and can't seem to find any tutorials that walk through this step.  Everything either stops just before this step OR starts just after it.

I have launched an AWS server (Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-Containers-2016.10.18 (ami-d08edfc7)) and installed node in the default directory.

I have put a file into the following content:

```
var http = require('http');
const PORT=8080; 
function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(PORT, function(){
     console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

I then open CMD, navigage into the directory where node is installed and run the program with:

```
node myServer.js
```

Next I open a browser and navigate to http://localhost:8080 and I am served some content.  Terrific.

**My question is** how do I go about making a request of that newly installed server from another machine over the internet.  My primitive guess was to simply navigate to the AWS machine's public IP, as displayed in the AWS console and include the port number.

So for example if my IP were 55.173.140.15 I would type in the address http://55.173.140.15:8080 and expect to see the page.  That is not working.  So what configuration step am I missing?

Comment: Disable windows firewall?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I went in and disabled it fully and then relaunched the server.  Still not able to connect.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't opened the port in the AWS Security Group assigned to your EC2 instance.